# Is there a way to add Microdata type for feeds?

Tags: seo, feed, microdata, schema.org

I am displaying the feeds from Facebook and Twitter on a site. For SEO purpose I came across this excellent site http://schema.org/. I read through the site but didn’t get a way to add Microdata to feeds.

Does anyone have idea? Also is there a better way to add SEO to feeds?

Comment: do you want to add seo to the feed (the link element) or the content within each post?

Comment: for both - the link and content

Comment: you can use microformats; they're not the "same" as microdata, but they're just as good and more highly used

Comment: what kind of 'feeds' ? rss? atom? .. what do you mean about 'feeds'? Per what i know, facebook returns html. Yes you'd be able to manipulate after-recieving in some php process before displaying on your page. If you recieve your facebook content via javascript, it will be useless.

Answer (score 1):

If you are displaying the feed entries on your page, you would be using HTML. If you use HTML5, you may use Microdata. If you can’t change the output on the server-side, you’d have to add the Microdata with JavaScript (if you are interested in search engines consuming your Microdata, then this would probably not work for most of them).

If you link to the feeds from your page, they are probably in XML (Atom, RSS, …). Microdata can only be used with (X)HTML5.

If you want to use the [schema.org vocabulary](http://schema.org/), you can use Microdata, RDFa Lite, JSON-LD, ….